# Passing attributes to Mongoid update_attributes()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I want to use this function from mongoid:

```
person.update_attributes(first_name: "Jean", last_name: "Zorg")
```

But I want to pass in all the attributes from another variable. How do I do that?

Edit: Thanks everyone for your reply. I'm new to ruby so at first I thought I just made a silly mistake with this. The bug was in a completely different place, the correct code, for your enjoyment:

```
  def twitter
    # Scenarios:
    # 1. Player is already signed in with his fb account:
    #    we link the accounts and update the information.
    # 2. Player is new: we create the account.
    # 3. Player is old: we update the player's information.
    # login with a safe write.
    puts "twitter"
    twitter_details = {
      twitter_name: env["omniauth.auth"]['user_info']['name'], 
      twitter_nick: env["omniauth.auth"]['user_info']['nickname'],
      twitter_uid: env["omniauth.auth"]['uid']
    }
    if player_signed_in?
      @player = Player.find(current_player['_id']) 
    else
      @player = Player.first(conditions: {twitter_uid: env['omniauth.auth']['uid']})
    end

    if @player.nil?
      @player = Player.create!(twitter_details)
    else
      @player.update_attributes(twitter_details)
    end

    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Twitter"
    sign_in_and_redirect @player, :event => :authentication
  end
```

Comment: You have the first and last names in a Hash?

Comment: Not understanding this, either. If you have a hash set in a variable, you can just pass that hash into the function...

Comment: @WattsInABox: Unless the Hash contains things that shouldn't be set in `person`, then you need to slice a piece out.

Comment: @muistooshort you're correct, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you look at the source code of Mongoid, you'll see the definition of `update_attributes` in the file 
`.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mongoid-2.3.1/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb`

```
# Update the document attributes in the datbase.                                                                                                         
#                                                                                                                                                        
# @example Update the document's attributes                                                                                                              
#   document.update_attributes(:title => "Sir")                                                                                                          
#                                                                                                                                                        
# @param [ Hash ] attributes The attributes to update.                                                                                                   
#                                                                                                                                                        
# @return [ true, false ] True if validation passed, false if not.                                                                                       
def update_attributes(attributes = {})
  write_attributes(attributes); save
end
```

It takes a Hash -- that means you can use a Hash as the variable that's passed in.
e.g.

```
my_attrs = {first_name: "Jean", last_name: "Zorg"}

person.update_attributes( my_attrs )
```

Answer (score 6):

The `update_attributes` method takes a Hash argument so if you have a Hash, `h`, with just `:first_name` and `:last_name` keys then:

```
person.update_attributes(h)
```

If your Hash has more keys then you can use [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to pull out just the ones you want:

```
person.update_attributes(h.slice(:first_name, :last_name))
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening in the update_attributes method and, indeed, across the Rails platform is variables get put into a hash internally, when necessary.

So the following are equivalent:

```
person.update_attributes(first_name: "Jean", last_name: "Zorg")
person.update_attributes({first_name: "Jean", last_name: "Zorg"})
person.update_attributes(name_hash)
```

Where name_hash is:

```
name_hash = {first_name: "Jean", last_name: "Zorg"}
```